# conjunction type traits in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

I need to check variadic arguments in `std::enable_if`:

With C++17 I would write:

```
template <typename A, typename ...B>
class Foo : public A, public B...
{

public:

    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<A> &&
        (std::is_default_constructible_v<B> && ...)>>
    Foo()
    {}
    
    Foo(A &&a, B && ... b)
       : A(std::forward<A>(a)),
       B(std::forward<B>(b))...
    {}

};
```

But C++11 doesn't have a feature of expanding parameter packs this way. Neither does it provides `std::conjunction`.

What is a simple way to implement conjunction with C++11?
I suppose SFINAE with recursion would suffice, but I cannot wrap my hand around it.

Comment: Have you tried to making your own `conjunction` using the possible implementation from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you. Somehow I missed it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a tool which will do the conjunction operation on variadic arguments.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class...> struct conjunction : std::true_type { };
template<class B1> struct conjunction<B1> : B1 { };
template<class B1, class... Bn>
struct conjunction<B1, Bn...> 
    : std::conditional<bool(B1::value), conjunction<Bn...>, B1>::type {};

template <typename A, typename ...B>
class Foo : public A, public B...
{

public:

    template <typename std::enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<A>::value &&
        conjunction<std::is_default_constructible<B>...>::value, bool>::type = true>
    Foo()
    {}
    
    Foo(A &&a, B && ... b)
       : A(std::forward<A>(a)),
       B(std::forward<B>(b))...
    {}

};

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {
    C(int x) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo<A, B> foo;
    //Foo<A, B, C> bar;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d3jvM4

based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction which is available in C++17.

Comment: Do consider not using a default template parameter and instead use a non-type default parameter.  Default type parameters are not considered part o the function signature so you can't overload with other templates that use SFINAE without giving them a different signature.  You can use `typename std::enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<A>::value &&
        conjunction<std::is_default_constructible<B>...>::value, bool>::type = true` instead

Comment: I would move the recursion into a context that is laziky evaluated.  I believe most compilers end up with O(n^2) template name length instantiated with the above design (C(a,b,c) instantiates C(b,c) which instantiates C(c)).  This of course only matters if you care about build times or if N is large.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to see the problem from a different perspective...

Given that, if I'm not wrong, a `std::tuple` is default constructible iff (if and only if) every type of the tuple is default constructible, what about

```
 template <typename
    = typename std::enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<std::tuple<A, B...>::value>::type>
 Foo()
  { }
```

or also

```
 template <typename = decltype(std::tuple<A, B...>())>
 Foo()
  { }
```

?

Comment: Nice, though it only supports `default_constructible`, and not a general `conjunction`.

Comment: In this specific case you don't have to declare your own `conjunction`. That is a better solution in particular to find if all the types are constructible. Though it suits my particular goal, I find your answer very appealing. But in general the question is about conjunction itself

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik - I've added the answer just to show a possible alternative solution to your specific problem, but you're right: isn't an answer to your exact question.

Comment: @max66 it is a very good answer to the specific problem:)